# Histogram chart getting cut when using package plot3D

Tags: r, histogram, plot3d

I'm trying to plot a simple histogram using `hist3D()` from plot3D package using the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plot3D)
data(iris)
iris=as.tibble(iris)

x=c(1,2)
y=x
z=matrix(rnorm(4,sd=0.5,mean=1),ncol=2,nrow=2)

pmat<-hist3D(x,y,
       z,
       border="black",
       axes=TRUE,
       expand=0.4,
       theta=40,phi=30,
       zmin=-1,
       margin=c(10,10),
       mar=c(10, 1, 0, 2),
       ticktype = "detailed",col="green",box=TRUE)
```

But the histogram get cut at the bottom:

[image]

So, I'm looking for a way to extends the width or the height of the canvas for `hist3D()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `par(xpd = NA)` before the `hist3D` call to allow your full device region to be used for plotting.  This might not be enough space; if not, set the margins to be really large as well.  For example,

```
par(xpd = NA, mar = c(10,10,10,10))
hist3D(x,y,
   z,
   border="black",
   axes=TRUE,
   expand=0.4,
   theta=40,phi=30,
   zmin=-1,
   margin=c(20,20),
   mar=c(10, 1, 0, 2),
   ticktype = "detailed",col="green",box=TRUE)
```

produces this for me:

[image: screenshot]

It's pretty ugly, but that's to be expected for a 3D histogram :-).

Comment: Yes ! Exactly what I was looking for thank you. Actually in a first place, I was drawing lines and they had unexpected sizes. Then, I found that they was cutted by the edge of canvas.